# Write function to loop over elements in jquery style library

Tags: javascript

I am writing a very simple jquery imitation library, to allow for some simple DOM manipulation.

I am writing methods to allow me change color of text etc. When I wish to change a class element color I have to use a loop in each method. Ideally I would like to have a function that does that loop for me that I could then use in each method. Unfortunately, my attempt at this is not working.

Please see my code below:

```
function _(elem) {
  this.classOrId(elem);
}

_.prototype = {
  add: function(text) {
    if (this.e.length >= 1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.e.length; i++) {
        this.e[i].innerHTML = this.e[i].innerHTML + text;
      }
    } else {
      this.e.innerHTML = this.e.innerHTML + text;
    }
    return this;
  },
  replace: function(text) {
    if (this.e.length >= 1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.e.length; i++) {
        this.e[i].textContent = text;
      }
    } else {
      this.e.textContent = text;
      document.body.appendChild(elem);
    }
    return this;
  }
}

_.prototype.classOrId = function(elem) {
  var classOrId = elem.charAt(0);
  if (classOrId === "#") {
    elem = this.sliceElement(elem);
    this.e = document.getElementById(elem);
    return this;
  } else if (classOrId === ".") {
    elem = this.sliceElement(elem)
    this.e = document.getElementsByClassName(elem);
    return this;
  }
};

_.prototype.sliceElement = function(elem) {
  var elem = elem.slice(1);
  return elem;
};
```

As you can see there is an awful lot of repetition in this code. I tried writing the following to cut down on the repition but it didn't work.
Any suggestions here would be greatly appreciated.

```
_.prototype.loopOverElements = function(effect) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.e.length; i++) {
    return this.e[i][effect];
  }
}
```

With the code below it does not recognise the javascript DOM methods such as `innerHTML`, `style` when they are passed into the function.

With the code above if I pass the effect into the loopOverElements function it shows that `console.log(this.e[i][effect])` is undefined when passed into the method.

Comment: what is loopOverElements supposed to do. Should it just loop through all the elements through the effect function?  If so, I think this should just work - effect(this.e[i]); http://jsbin.com/buhezu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: It is to be used to cut out the repition of me using a loop in each method of my code

Comment: Well in that case doesn't my code work for ur use case?

Comment: no, unfortunately not :-( ... It must be possible, but maybe not.. what i wrote feels dirty, repeating that loop in each method... i dont like it

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. Like what is 'effect' parameter? Can you modify the demo I sent to use the 'loopOverElements' based on ur use case. After seeing how you want to use it will be more clear what needs to be done.

Comment: parameter should be an effect such as `style.fontSize` or `style.backgroundColor`. I have updated the jsfiddle with the complete code - http://jsbin.com/lahikotojo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100224/discussion-between-paul-fitzgerald-and-blessenm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably post this on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but I'll give it a shot. The first thing bothering me is all the `if (this.e.length >= 1) { } else { }`. Make `e` an array even when there is only one element, only a variable's value should "variate" not its type.

About `classOrId()`, it can be reduced to one line thanks to [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (returning the needed array). So the code becomes:

```
function _(elem) {
    var about = {
        Name: "pQuery",
        Version: 0.1,
        Author: "Paul Fitzgerald"
    }

    if (elem) {
        if (window === this) {
            return new _(elem);
        }
        this.e = document.querySelectorAll(elem); // no need for classOrId() anymore
    } else {
        return about;
    }
}

_.prototype = {
    add: function (text) {
        // no if else anymore
        for (var i = 0; i < this.e.length; i++) {
            this.e[i].innerHTML = this.e[i].innerHTML + text;
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

About the repetition, separate the functions into similar usages, for example you could write a function for all the operations related to style:

```
_.prototype = {
    _eachStyle: function (prop, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.e.length; i++) {
          this.e[i].style[prop] = value;
        }

        return this;
    },
    hide: function () {
        return _eachStyle('display', 'none');
    },
    color: function (color) {
        return _eachStyle('color', color);
    }
}
```

For the base properties:

```
_.prototype = {
    _each: function (prop, value, append) {
        append = append || false; // by default, replace the value
        for (var i = 0; i < this.e.length; i++) {
          this.e[i][prop] = append ? element[prop] + value : value;
        }
        return this;
    },
    add: function (text) {
        return _each('innerHTML', text, true);
    },
    replace: function (text) {
        return _each('textContent', text);
    }
}
```

Similarely, for a function to be called on all elements:

```
_.prototype = {
    _eachFn: function (fn, args) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.e.length; i++) {
          this.e[i][fn](args);
        }
        return this;
    },
    remove: function () {
        return _eachFn('remove');
    },
}
```

Comment: brilliant! although the forEach function doesn't work

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: this.e.forEach is not a function(…)`

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Weird, `e` is an array (empty if no element found) so `forEach()` is always there unless you're using a very old browser.

Comment: im using the latest chrome :-0

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Yes if I set `this.e` to a static array. I found the issue, querySelectorAll returns a NodeList object not an array. I think a simple for should work, I'm doing some tests.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald, so it works with a simple for loop. I updated my answer. There is still room for improvement (_each and _eachStyle are close) but it's a good start.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned earlier in the chat session, you basically want to apply transformations on each DOM element in a array. Using a function that defines what needs to be done and mapping each element through this function is the ideal approach.

```
_.prototype.loopOverElements = function(effect) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.e.length; i++) {
    effect(this.e[i]);
  }
};

And I can use it as

var test = new _('.test');
test.loopOverElements(function(elem) {
  elem.innerHTML += " Modified";
});
```

[**Here is a working demo for this implementation.**](http://jsbin.com/buhezu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

But your requirement is that you want a loop method that has 2 parameters -`propertyName` and `value`. There are many problems associated with this like  suppose the property is `style.color`. You cannot access that property using `this.e[i]['style.color']`. Its not valid js. It should be `this.e[i]['style']['color']`. So basically `this.e[i][effect]` will not work in this case. Library's like lodash have a `_.set` method where you can specify a property path and the value will be correctly set. [**You can see the implementation here**](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.10.1/lodash.src.js#L10155).

I've created a naive implementation of the set method.

```
_.prototype.set = function set(obj, path, value) {
  var codeString = 'obj';
  codeString += path.split('.').reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev += '.' + curr;
  }, '');

  codeString += ' = value';
  eval(codeString);
};

Now your loop code looks like

_.prototype.loopOverElements = function(property, value){
  for(var i = 0; i < this.e.length; i++){
    this.set(this.e[i], property, value);
  }
};

And it can be used like

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var test = new _('.testClass');
  test.loopOverElements('style.color', 'red');
});
```

**[Here is a working demo for this implementation.](http://jsbin.com/buhezu/5/edit?html,js,console,output)**

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets notation, i.e. `[effect]` instead of `.effect`:

```
_.prototype.loopOverElements = function(effect){
  for(var i = 0; i < this.e.length; i++){
    return this.e[i][effect];
  }
}
```

See also [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets).

Comment: for this when I pass in an 'effect' it says `innerHTML` is not defined

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald What do you get when you `console.log(this.e[i])`? Also, are you passing `innerHTML` as parameter, or string `"innerHTML"`?

Comment: if i pass it in as a string it returns the html array of classes, but doesn't perform th update to the elements styling

Comment: if you would like to play around with the whole code in your text editor you can find it here : `https://github.com/Pau1fitz/pQuery/blob/master/index.html` I always find it easier to answer questions on this by doing this and looking at the code in my own text editor

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to solve your problem is using a callback function:

```
_.prototype.applyOnElements = function(callback) {
   for(var i = 0; i < this.e.length; i++){
     callback(this.e[i]);
   }
}
```

And you use it this way:

```
this.applyOnElements(function(element) {
    element.style.color = myColor;
});
```

Then there is place to improvement by replacing the loop by [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and including your `if (this.e is array) then ... else ... endif` inside this function to avoid more code duplication.